# How do I say "to pass/fail a test"?

Tags: translation, verbs

How can I say *I passed the test* or *I failed the test*? Using our grading system, *failing* would mean getting an F, while an E or higher is what is required to "pass." I've seen *sukcesi* and *malsukcesi* in this context. I don't think this expresses quite the same thing, since one may pass without succeeding, and getting a lower grade than one aimed for.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking for ways to say "I passed the test" without implying that the mark fulfilled your expectations, i.e. without saying *sukcesi*?

Answer (score 7):

Most of the time, the expression used is something like *(mal)sukcese fari/trapasi la ekzamenon* or *plenumi la ekzamenon* or *(mal)prosperi en la ekzameno*. However, to avoid implying that a bare pass was a success, you could use ***elteni*** ("withstand"), which appears in the *Fundamenta Krestomatio* in this sense. Thus: *Mi eltenis la ekzamenon. Mi ricevis sufiĉajn notojn en la ekzameno kaj estis akceptita*.

- *ricevi (ne)sufiĉajn notojn en la ekzameno* — to (not) receive high enough marks in the exam
- *(ne, apenaŭ) elteni la ekzamenon* — to (not, barely) withstand the exam
- *meza, bona, supera noto* — middling, good, superior mark
- *nesufiĉa, apenaŭ sufiĉa noto* — failing mark, bare pass

Another possibility is *transpasi* ("get to the other side of"), but I am not confident that it would be understood as "to pass" given the similarity to *trapasi*.

Answer (score 5):

The expression I've always heard and used is *sukcesi en la ekzameno.* It means "to pass."

Variations of this phrase occur multiple times in the Tekstaro.

- *9 gestudentoj sukcesis en siaj ekzamenoj pri Esperanto*
- *Via tre afabla kaj mirige rapida respondo montris, ke vi sukcesis en tiu testo.*
- *Stanislava Chrdlová [...] sukcesis en la ekzameno de ĈEA pri kapablo instrui en 1972.*
- *Sekvis disdono de atestiloj al la 8 el 13 kandidatoj, kiuj sukcesis en la ekzameno.*
- *Preskaŭ ĉiuj kursfinintoj sukcesis en la lingva ekzameno de REJM*
- *deko sukcesis en bakalaŭriga studfina ekzameno.*

According to PIV *sukcesi* and *malsukcesi en la ekzameno* are *Zamenhofaj*.

To the concern that it's possible to successfully pass a test without successfully reaching specific goals regarding grades, this is certainly true, but it doesn't change the meaning of the expression *sukcesi en la ekzameno*. In all of the examples above, it's clear that the various people have passed, but nowhere are specific grades mentioned.

As for alternate expressions, the only one that is is in wide use is *trapasi*. I did some checking in tekstaro.

- *trapasi/sukcesi* - about equally common - a dozen hits.
- *elteni* - not used outside of *Fundamenta Krestomatio*.
- *sukcese fari* - two hits.
- *sukcese ekzameniĝi* - one hit.
- *plenumi* - this means something different.
- *prosperi* - not used.
- *sufiĉajn notojn* - no hits (including variations)

Comment: This answer was downvoted without commentary. I have clarified with additional references. If there is an issue with this answer, I hope someone will let me know.

Comment: Your answer gives completely correct information, but I suspect the downvote happened because the question is mainly asking for _alternatives_ to *sukcesi* (which the asker already mentioned).

Comment: Possibly. However, the original question assumes that *sukcesi en la ekzameno" does **not** mean "pass". It does mean pass. I will clarify my answer.

Comment: The question was how to say "I passed or failed the test". Possible ways of saying that which are not actually used don't answer the question. The poster isn't really asking for alternatives, but rather questioning the actual usage in Esperanto. Tomaso's answer clarifies the correct usage.